# Perl Regex 'e' (eval) modifier with s///

Tags: regex, perl, modifier

I'm having a little trouble comprehending this simple use of the /e regex modifier.

```
my $var = 'testing';
$_ = 'In this string we are $var the "e" modifier.';

s/(\$\w+)/$1/ee;

print;
```

Returns: "In this string we are testing the "e" modifier."

I cannot see why two 'e' modifiers are required.  As far as I can see, $1 should capture '$var' from the string and a single 'e' modifier should then be able to replace the variable with its value.  I must be misunderstanding something however, since trying the above code with just one 'e' modifier does not visibly replace anything in the string.

Excuse me for asking such a simple question!

Thanks.

Comment: note that "e" is not a regex modifier, since it does not affect the regex! It only affects the replacement part. So "e" modifies the s/// operator, not the regex.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It’s not exactly a “simple” question, so don’t beat yourself up.

The issue is that with a single `/e`, the RHS is understood to be code whose `eval`’d result is used for the replacement.

What is that RHS?  It’s `$1`.  If you evaluated `$1`, you find that contains **the string** `$var`.  It does not contain the contents of said variable, just  `$` followed by a `v` followed by an `a` followed by an `r`.

Therefore you must evaluate it twice, once to turn `$1` into `$var`, then again to turn the previous result of `$var` into the string `"testing"`. You do that by having the double `ee` modifier on the [`s` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer).

You can check this pretty easily by running it with one `/e` versus with two of them. Here’s a demo a both, plus a third way that uses symbolic dereferencing — which, because it references the package symbol table, works on package variables only.

```
use v5.10;

our $str = q(In this string we are $var the "e" modifier.);
our $var = q(testing);

V1: {
    local $_ = $str; 
    s/(\$\w+)/$1/e;
    say "version 1: ", $_;

}

V2: {
    local $_ = $str;
    s/(\$\w+)/$1/ee;
    say "version 2: ", $_;
}

V3: {
    no strict "refs";
    local $_ = $str;
    s/\$(\w+)/$$1/e;
    say "version 3: ", $_;
}
```

When run, that produces:

```
version 1: In this string we are $var the "e" modifier.
version 2: In this string we are testing the "e" modifier.
version 3: In this string we are testing the "e" modifier.
```

Comment: That's great, thank you.

As a curiosity, why does producing the regex s/(\$\w+)/$1/ with NO modifier still replace it with the captured value ($var)?  It seems to me that that is what the first /e is there for?

Comment: @user761513: With no modifier, `$1` as replacement text is used as a string. With a single `e`, it's used as an expression, with exactly the same outcome. To see the difference, compare `s/…/$1 (hello)/` (a string) with `s/…/uc($1)/e` (an expression).

Comment: Specifically, with no modifier, the replacement text acts like a _double quoted_ string.  Hence `$1` interpolates to what was captured by the first set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 9):

To be clear, the `s//ee` form is not modifying your regex pattern or regex interpretation at all. It is an optional treatment of the replacement side string after the regex is performed. (See [PERLOP Regex Quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators))

The `e` or `ee` just get mixed into the PATTERN side regex options in the `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer` form.

From Perlop:

> Options are as with m// with the
>   addition of the following replacement
>   specific options:
>
> ```
> e Evaluate the right side as an expression.
> ee  Evaluate the right side as a string then eval the result.
> r   Return substitution and leave the original string untouched.
> ```

You can see the same `e` vs `ee` type behavior in non regex situations, as this example shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my $var = "var's contents";
my $str='"-> $var <-"';
print eval('$str'), "\n";        # equivalent to s//e
print eval(eval('$str')), "\n";  # equivalent to s//ee
```

Output:

```
"-> $var <-"
-> var's contents <-
```

Comment: What does `# use strinct` do? ;-}

Comment: [Rejected as an edit]

A final note, just for completeness: You can add even more `e`s, it is not because the documentation stops there that it is not doable:

    my $testing = 'Phew!';
    my $var = '$testing';

    $_ = 'We are $var the "e" modifier.';
    s/(\$\w+)/$1/e;
    print;

    $_ = 'We are $var the "e" modifier.';
    s/(\$\w+)/$1/ee;
    print;

    $_ = 'We are $var the "e" modifier.';
    s/(\$\w+)/$1/eee;
    print;

producing

    We are $var the "e" modifier.
    We are $testing the "e" modifier.
    We are Phew! the "e" modifier.

Comment: @thewolf Could you please edit your post with my modification?

Answer (score -1):

Try the rename utility from the latest perl package with:

```
rename -v 's/\b(\w)/uc($1)/eg' *
```

Here, pattern `\b` find the word boundary, and the `e` modifier enables evaluation in the substitution, and `g` replace the all occurrence.

You may also rename to camelCase with:

```
rename -v 's/\b(\w)/uc($1)/eg' *
rename -v 's/^(\w)/lc($1)/e' *
rename -v 's/\s+//g' *
```