# perl: substitute pattern with pattern of different size

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

here is my string `A B C D` and I want to replace `A` by `123` and `C` by `456` for example. However this doesn't work.

```
$string=~ s/A|B|C|D/123|B|456|D/;
```

I want this `123 B 456 D` but i get this `123|B|456|D B C D`

Probably because the number of characters in my two patterns is different.

Is there a way to substitute patterns of different size using some other piece of code ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should work. what is your Output?

Comment: The relative sizes of the pattern and the substituting string do not matter. Your example code works perfectly fine with me. Can you show the complete code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this using eval  (untested).

```
$string=~ s/(A)|C/ length($1) ? '123': '456'/eg;
```

Using the *eval* flag in the `s///` form means to evaluate the *replacement*
side as a line of code that returns a value.

In this case it executes a ternary conditional in the replacement code.

It's sort of like an inline regex callback.
It's much more complicated though since it can be like `s///eeg` so
better to refer to the docs.

Remember, *eval* is really evil, misspelled !!

Comment: It works, thank you ! Could you explain the formula a little ?

Comment: Note that, despite the somewhat misleading abbreviation, `/e` really has nothing to do with `eval`. It just causes the right-hand side of the substitution to be parsed (at compile time) as Perl code, rather than as a (double-quoted) string. Just to confuse things further, `/ee` [really does](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer) apply `eval` to the result of the substitution, and does share its "evilness" (inefficiency, lack of compile-time error checking, very high risk of security holes if applied to user input).

Answer (score 7):

You're getting what I'd expect you to get. Your regex looks for *one* occurrence of either an `'A'` or a `'B'` or a `'C'` or a `'D'` and replaces it with the *literal string* `'123|B|456|D'`. Hence `'A B C D'` -> `'123|B|456|D B C D'`

So it finds the first occurrence, the `'A'` and replaces it with the string you specified. An *alternation* matches various strings, but the pipe characters mean nothing in the replacement slot.

What you need to do is create a mapping from input to output, like so:

```
my %map = ( A => '123', C => '456' );
```

Then you need to use it in the replacements. Let's give you a search expression:

```
my $search = join( '|', keys %map );
```

Now let's write the substitution (I prefer braces when I code substitutions that have code in them:

```
$string =~ s{($search)}{ $map{$1} }g;
```

The `g` switch means we match every part of the string we can, and the `e` switch tells Perl to *evaluate* the replacement expression as Perl code.

The output is `'123 B 456 D'`

Comment: There's no need for the `/e` modifier when the replacement can be expressed as a simple interpolated string. `$string =~ s/($search)/$map{$1}/g` is fine

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with two substitutions:

```
$string =~ s/A/123/g;
$string =~ s/B/456/g;
```

or even (using an inline `for` loop as a shorthand to apply multiple substitutions to one string):

```
s/A/123/g, s/B/456/g for $string;
```

Of course, for more complicated patterns, this may not produce the same results as doing both substitutions in one pass; in particular, this may happen if the patterns can overlap (as in A = `YZ`, B = `XY`), or if pattern B can match the string substituted for pattern A.

If you wish to do this in one pass, the most general solution is to use the [`/e` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082219/perl-regex-e-eval-modifier-with-s), which causes the substitution to be interpreted as Perl code, as in:

```
$string =~ s/(A|B)/ $1 eq 'A' ? '123' : '456' /eg;
```

You can even include multiple expressions, separated by semicolons, inside the substitution; the last expression's value is what will be substituted into the string.  If you do this, you may find it useful to use [paired delimiters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for readability, like this:

```
$string =~ s{(A|B)}{
    my $foo = "";
    $foo = '123' if $1 eq 'A';
    $foo = '456' if $1 eq 'B';
    $foo;  # <-- this is what gets substituted for the pattern
}eg;
```

If your patterns are constant strings (as in the simple examples above), an even more efficient solution is to use a look-up hash, as in:

```
my %map = ('A' => '123', 'B' => '456');
$string =~ s/(A|B)/$map{$1}/g;
```

With this method, you don't even need the `/e` modifier (although, for this specific example, adding it would make no difference).  The advantage of using `/e` is that it lets you implement more complicated rules for choosing the replacement than a simple hash lookup would allow.

Answer (score 0):

String="A B C D"

echo $String | perl - pi - e 's/A/123/' && perl - pi - e 's/C/456/'