# Escaping double quotes fix

Tags: perl

I cannot find the resources for this. I want to escape double quotes with perl and i am new to this language.

Here's what I have:

```
$comment =~ s/\"/\\\"/g;
```

It doesn't seem to be working. What is a proper solution?

Comment: `perl -E '$comment="a\"b";say$comment;$comment=~s/"/\\"/g;say$comment'` shows that your code does his job, so the problem is probaby somewhere else.. Please show us your entire code so we can help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to escape the quotes?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot because some of the data has double quotes and its causing an issue with our xml

Comment: I assume you mean attribute values, right? You don't have to escape quotes in text nodes in XML.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yeh this solution works though. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to insert things that would need escaping, and without counting backslashes

```
$comment =~ s/"/q(\")/eg;
```

With `/e` modifier the replacement side is evaluated as code, and the result used as replacement. See it [in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) and, say, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082219/perl-regex-e-eval-modifier-with-s). Here this is used to form a string literal with `\`, by `q()`.

Note though that in this simple case `s/"/\"/` works fine.  There is probably more going on in your code, or your quotes come already escaped in which case extra `\` affect what you see later.

Answer (score 0):

No counting required:

```
$comment =~ s.(?=").\\.g;
```