# security concerns with Perl /e modifier

Tags: perl, security

Let's say that I have a Perl script which contains a substitution command which takes replacement string as a positional parameter and uses `/e` modifier:

```
perl -pe 's/abc/$ARGV[0]/ge;'
```

Are there any security concerns with this approach? I mean is it possible to give such positional parameter value which causes perl to execute an unwanted function? I mean something similar: `perl -pe 's/abc//;unlink ("/tmp/file");'`.

Comment: Possible [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082219/perl-regex-e-eval-modifier-with-s), but not certain. I've never used the `e` regex modifier to the point I'd need to worry about it. Valid question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/abc/$ARGV[0]/ge'
```

> Are there any security concerns with this approach? I mean is it possible to give such positional parameter value which causes perl to execute an unwanted function?

---

In
[`perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)
in the section
[*Regexp Quote-Like Operators*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)
it explains

- **e** Evaluate the right side as an expression
- **ee** Evaluate the right side as a string then `eval` the result.

But this isn't entirely true. In both cases the "right side"—the *replacement*—is evaluated as if it were a `do` block<sup>†</sup>. In the  first case the result provides the replacement string, while in the second the result is passed to `eval` and the result of *that* provides the replacement string. There is no distinction whereby the *replacement* is evaluated as an "expression" in the first place and as a "string" in the second.

Both `/e` and `/ee` allow for any valid Perl code sequence, including loops, conditionals, and multiple statements, and aren't limited to a single expression

There's never anything wrong with `$ARGV[0]` in isolation. Tainted strings become dangerous only if you *execute* them, either as Perl, using `eval`, or as shell code using `system`, `qx//`, or backticks. So it's fine in the replacement part of a substitution with a single `/e` modifier

But if you use something else in the replacement, for instance

```
perl -pe 's/abc/qx{$ARGV[0]}/eg'
```

then that parameter will be executed as a shell command, so it clearly isn't safe. But then nor is

```
perl -pe 's/abc/unlink glob "*.*"/eg'
```

so you have to be sensible about it

***What is dangerous*** is the double-e modifier `/ee`, which treats the replacement as a Perl `do` block and then does an `eval` on the result. So something like

```
    s/abc/$ARGV[0]/eeg
```

is very unsafe, because you could run your code like this

```
    perl -pe 's/abc/$ARGV[0]/eeg' 'unlink glob *.*'
```

With just a single `/e` this would just replace `abc` with the *string*
`unlink glob *.*`
in `$ARGV[0]`. But using `/ee`, the string is passed to `eval` and all your files are deleted!

Remember this:

- **/e** — replacement is an *expression* (a `do` block)
- **/ee** — replacement is an *expression* (a `do` block) and the result is passed to *`eval`*

<sup>†</sup>
*This is why I choose to use braces to delimit substitutions that use one of the `/e` modes. With* 
`s{abc}{ $ARGV[0] }ge` *the* replacement *looks much more like the block of code that it is than if I had used the usual slashes*

Comment: *"But this isn't entirely true"* This is misleading and worthy of a bug report, so I shall issue one when I get back to a working PC. I'm currently in a hotel in Athens with a drained laptop and no charger, and have only my tablet to talk to the world!

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `/ee`, there's no inherent risk to `/e` as it doesn't invoke the Perl parser. It simply causes code *in the source file* to be evaluated, just like how `map BLOCK LIST` and `for (LIST) BLOCK` evaluate their `BLOCK`.

Note that

```
s{$foo}{$bar}g
```

is simply short for

```
s{$foo}{ qq{$bar} }eg
```

So if you're ok with

```
perl -pe's/abc/$ARGV[0]/g'
```

then you're ok with

```
perl -pe's/abc/"$ARGV[0]"/eg'
```

and the virtually identical

```
perl -pe's/abc/$ARGV[0]/eg'
```