# How to make Perl apply regex matching groups, when the replace string is provided via environment variable?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, environment-variables

I have this perl command:

```bash
# Result: o
#
echo foo | perl -pe 's/f(o)o/$1/'
```

I'd like the replacement expression to be passed via env variable:

```bash
echo foo | REPLACE='$1' perl -pe 's/f(o)o/$ENV{REPLACE}/'
```

however, in this case, Perl does not interpret the matching variable `$1`; instead, it just replaces it with the env variable value, so that the result is `$1`.

I know I can work this around via Bash string interpolation:

```bash
REPLACE='$1'
echo foo | perl -pe 's/f(o)o/'"$REPLACE"'/'
```

however, this is hackish (and limited).

Is the a more idiomatic Perl way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3):

The string `eval` is a little insecure, but

```
echo foo | REPLACE='$1' perl -pe 's/f(o)o/$ENV{REPLACE}/ee'
```

works.

Comment: Now that you've provided the related terminology, I've found a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6082219.

Comment: Also, unlike the OP's hackish solution, this doesn't work for `REPLACE='a$1'`. That said, `REPLACE='"a$1"'` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `$ENV{REPLACE}` as a template. [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution) provides the tools to work with such templates.

```bash
perl -MString::Substitution=sub_modify \
   -pe'sub_modify( $_, qr/f(o)o/, $ENV{REPLACE} )'
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems that the module required is not provided by a standard Ubuntu installation